# How to avoid circular definition in racket language

Tags: user-interface, racket, definition, circular-dependency

I tried to write simple gui to modify it’s text then copy it's content to text2.
But the call function can't be defined because its owner (text) is not defined yet.

This is the warning :

> "cannot reference an identifier before its definition"

Is there anyway I could either:

1. assign callback later?
2. avoid circular reference?

Below is the code :

```
#lang racket/gui

(define toplevel (new frame% [label "MD View"] [width 800] [height 300]))

(define canvas (new editor-canvas% [parent toplevel] [style '(no-hscroll)]))
(define canvas2 (new editor-canvas% [parent toplevel] [style '(no-hscroll)]))


(define text2 (new text%))

(define text (new text%
                  [callback (send text2 insert (send text get-text)) ]
                  )) ;; warning here

(send canvas set-editor text)
(send canvas2 set-editor text2)

(send text auto-wrap #t)
(send text set-padding 10 10 10 10)

(send text2 auto-wrap #t)
(send text2 set-padding 10 10 10 10)

(new button% [parent toplevel]
             [label "write"]
             ; Callback procedure for a button click:
             [callback (lambda (button event)
                         (send text2 insert "written"))])

(new button% [parent toplevel]
             [label "copy"]
             ; Callback procedure for a button click:
             [callback (lambda (button event)
                         (send text2 insert (send text get-text)))])

(send toplevel show #t)
```

Comment: There are two problems: first, you're *evaluating* `(send text2 insert (send text get-text))`, but a callback is a procedure; second, `text%` does not even have a `callback` field, so you need to think of something else, such as subclassing `text%` to do something when it changes.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Thank you.  I'll look for the documentations on text% classes and to find the trigger when it changes.  Many thanks.